# Explaining Johnson Lindenstrauss lemma simply

Tags: dimensionality-reduction

I can't get my head around this concept of Johnson Lindenstrauss lemma which uses random projections, and I cannot find a simple explanation or example of how this works for a novice to understand. Please may I have explained in a simple way how it works for somebody that is not overly mathematically literate?